# Django Class-based Form is not displayed

Tags: python, django, forms

New in Django. I'm trying to show form, but have instead it:
**messag.views.CommentAdd object at 0x037860D0**

forms.py:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


class AjaxableResponseMixin(object):
    """
    Mixin to add AJAX support to a form.
    Must be used with an object-based FormView (e.g. CreateView)
    """

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxableResponseMixin, self).form_invalid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=400)
        else:
            return response

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # We make sure to call the parent's form_valid() method because
        # it might do some processing (in the case of CreateView, it will
        # call form.save() for example).
        response = super(AjaxableResponseMixin, self).form_valid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            data = {
                'pk': self.object.pk,
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            return response
```

views.py:

```
class CommentAdd(AjaxableResponseMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['author_name', 'text', 'root']


class ShowTree(ListView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'comment_tree.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ShowTree, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comment_form'] = CommentAdd()
        return context
```

Comment: When I use simply class CommentAdd in urls.py url(r'^add/$', CommentAdd.as_view(), name='add'), - all works correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you need to pass an form instance and you are passing a class based view. CreateView is a [class based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/), not a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

It could be easier to create a CreateView like [in the example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example) and get the data to build the list in get_context_data()

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I can't understand how to pass form instance in my ShowTree.get_context_data function

Comment: If you make a CreateView you won't need to pass the form instance in the get_context_data function.

Comment: The Django example doesn't use get_context_data to pass the form instance, I suggest that you use get_context_data to get the queryset of Comments to create the list

Comment: Yes, and I need comments and form in one page. How to add this form CommentAdd(AjaxableResponseMixin, CreateView) to one page with comments, may be with templatetag?

Comment: With templatetag I have the same <messag.templatetags.forma.CommentAdd object at 0x036D5390> :(

Comment: Eugene, please read again my comment, it's very clear. First create a CreateView to add the comments. Once you have it working and you are adding comments to the database you can pass the list of comments to the template using get_context_data() and then customize the template to show the comments.